# Don't use sticky if element is larger than screen height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sticky

I've a sidebar which is positioned `sticky` but in some cases larger than the height of the screen.

If the sidebar is in fact larger as the screen height, I don't want it to stick on the top. It should scroll down with the content of the page.

I'm using Bootstraps `sticky-top` class for that.

It has the following attributes:

```
.sticky-top {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
}
```

I changed the `top: 0` to `top: 50px` in my case because I need the space above.

Here's some example code: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/ZEaOXwo

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="toc sticky-top">
                <nav class="list-group">
                        Links (see example)
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                Content (see example)
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69408182/1788961) and added the following code to my class:

```
.toc {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

But that doesn't help.

Is there a pure CSS solution for that or do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: i have updated answer+code please look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hope this [pen](https://codepen.io/neptotech/full/RwjRjOZ) helps

#### Some explanations:

- in js we use `.offsetHeight`&`.clientHeight` to get height we check weather this height(`493px`) + `50px` offset is more than screen height or not.
- When screen size is small we set position to `static`
- Also we set `margin-top: 50px` instead of `top: 50px`
  because `top` works only for `sticky` and `margin-top` works for `static`

Comment: this loooks promising. Thank you. But how can I add the height from JS to the CSS?

Comment: yes ,i thought you need to avoid `js` but if you don't want to avoid `js` yes you can

Comment: The height is always different, so I can't use a fixed height in CSS. Can you give me an example how to add the height from JS to CSS?

Comment: @Cray i have updated code please look into it

Comment: Thank you, it works fine in your pen!  Unfortunately not on my site because of some "Safe" jQuery mode in WordPress. But that's not part of the quetion. So thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but maybe using the `calc()` in your css could help you.

```css
.toc{
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added that to my code example but the sidebar is still sticked to the top

Comment: @Cray You wanted this element as a sticky element always, but with `50px` offset from the top?

Comment: No :-) It is always sticky at the moment. But if the element is higher than the screen height, it shouldn't be sticky

Answer (score 1):

For aside blocks that higher then window height you can use smartSticky script
Just add "data-smartsticky" atribute to your aside block
https://www.npmjs.com/package/smartsticker
Parent block of sticky block must be height 100%, or for flex - flex-grow:1